# Nivo Slider Thumbnail / ControlNav not positioning inside slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nivo-slider

This is the first time i'm trying out Nivo Slider, so bear with me here --

I'm trying to position my controlNav thumbnails **INSIDE** the slider (I want it in the center, 15px from the bottom of the slider), but so far using **position:absolute** and **left** and **top** attributes just make the entire positioning of the thumbnails position around the body instead of the slider.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm looking online for solutions but I just can't find any. Maybe I'm searching for the wrong keywords?

The site I'm testing it out with is [link removed]. I've reset the thumbnails to the original centered below slider layout, if you want to fiddle with it inside the console it'll be easier.

Answer (score 3):

If when you say "thumbnails", you mean the small pager icons then you can change the css to:

```
#front-showcase .nivo-controlNav {
z-index: 10;
position: relative;
bottom: 40px;
}
```

Here I removed display:block and you can adjust the 40px to what ever will suit your layout needs.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, set the `position`ing properties on `.nivo-control` instead of `nivo-controlNAV`.

This worked for me by adding to your `<head>`:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .nivo-control {
        position:relative;
        top:-45px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: nope. that just positions all the thumbnails together. I'm pretty sure its edited inside the controlNav... i tried it out just now, lumped every single thumbnail together.

Comment: done! anyway, there's a small issue -- i'm having a bit of an extra height on my #front-showcase -- is there any way I can get rid of it?

Comment: Yes, mToce actually did it right, you should use `bottom` instead. Negative positioning causes extra space. Could also use negative `margin-top` values.

Comment: hmm, I've realized the :relative attribute is the one affecting the extra height, and also disables my left and right navigation!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, looks like i've found the answer with help from @aditya and @mToce's answers.

Seems that I forgot about positioning the #front-showcase as a relative element, thus making the controlNav position itself with the body element instead of the slider element.

For more information, read this :

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

I've solved the thing by entering position:relative; inside my #front-showcase, and entering position:absolute; inside .controlNav.

Hope this helps!